# This is a reiteration of the enabling cookies posted that somebody wanted me to resubmit for clarity

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762369/how-to-enable-cookies)

The `readCookie` is right under the `greetUser` function. I put in the `writeCookie` function but it causes the `alert` boxes not to show. So I commented it out.

This is about the cookies not working. I'm suppose to sort the username it a variable so that `iRock` will remember the name and use it in the prompt.

It seems like the last part of the code works because I get the `alert` boxes, but I don't get the first and second alert boxes. The page is suppose to open in an alert box saying, "Hello, I am a pet rock." but it doesn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1    /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>iRock - The Virtual Pet Rock</title>
<link href="donut_stylesheet/donut.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type ="text/javascript">
var userName;

function resizeRock(){
    document.getElementById("rockImg").style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - 100) * 0.9;
}

function greetUser(){
    userName = readCookie("rock_username");
    if(userName)
        alert("Hello " + userName + ", I missed you.");
    else 
        alert("Hello, I am your pet rock");
}

function touchRock(){
    if(userName)
        alert("I like attention," + userName + ". Thank you.");
}

userName = prompt("What is your name?", "Enter name here.");
if(userName) 
    alert("It is good to meet you, " + userName + ".");
    //writeCookie(irock_username", userName, 1 * 365);

document.getElementById("rockImg").src = "rock_happy.png";
setTimeout("document.getElementById(('rockImg').src = 'images/rock.png';", 5 * 60 * 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="resizeRock(); greetUser(); onResize="resizeRock();">
 <img id="rockImg" src="images/rock.png" alt="iRock" style="cursor:pointer"    onClick="touchRock();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A good read: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Where is `writeCookie()` and `readCookie()` defined? Also, you have a stray `"` on the `writeCookie()` line, and there is a missing `"` after the end of the `onload` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built in `readCookie` or `writeCookie` functions in JavaScript. You will have to supply your own, [like this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

```
function writeCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Comment: This is homework and I'm finding that some aspects of our assignment doesn't match what goes on in the real world.